# Rails 5 - datatables using Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Can anyone help - I am using jquery datatables in rails 5 with bootstrap gem.  The datatable does not appear correctly and looks like the styling is all messed up - it just doesnt look like styling has been applied.  Perhaps its due to the way I have installed it all, but I couldn't find a definitive guide.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
```

application.scss:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery3
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require bootstrap
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

HTML:

```
 <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

I should note that I am also using a bootswatch theme.  So in my assets I have a `bootstrap.scss` and a `bootswatch.scss`

I'm not sure if there is conflicting styling going on here.

I did have this in my application.scss but I removed it as it looks like its for bootstrap 3:

```
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

When I removed this, the styling goes away, but with it added, the styling on the table is all squashed a bit.

[image]

The image above is how it looks if you have the following in application.js and scss:

```
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

if I take these lines out it looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the "squashed table"?

Comment: added see the show 10 entries and the text at the bottom.  I removed the text in the table as its not relevant

Comment: The gem doesn't seem to work with bootstrap 4 as there are no instructions for it

Comment: The jQuery data tables gem? Should I just use bootstrap 3? How would I do that? Would I need to change the bootstrap gem just